# Do I get less scrap if I "soften up" an enemy ship before I board and finish off the crew?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Sometimes, to make boarding a ship easier, I'll send off a volley or two of burst lasers to knock out the medical bay or injure the crew before I teleport over to fight them.

When I do this, of course, it causes several points of damage to the enemy ship's hull.

Does it make any difference in the amount of scrap I receive at the end of the fight whether I weaken the enemy ship in this way, or capture it by teleport without firing a shot?

(My impression is that it doesn't, but I'm looking for something more solid than a hunch.)

Comment: This question was discussed at http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of

Answer (score 10):

According to this [wiki page](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Rewards) (and to this [Arqade page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135790/does-the-flavor-text-indicate-which-rewards-i-got), where a rather similar question is answered), the default reward system does not take the "health" of the enemy ship into account when the ship survives. It is only a matter of probability between the possible rewards triggered by the "killing the crew" victory.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Developer, it does not.

Update: It was a comment made by the Developer on the now-defunct Penny Arcade Report website back in the day. Apologies for not linking to the source originally.

Comment: Hi! Do you have any sort of link or source as to where you got this information that you can edit into your post?

Comment: @JeffreyLin it answers the question very well, it's only a matter of no sources.