# Does the flavor text indicate which rewards I got?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

After defeating an enemy, the flavor text will say things like "*leaving behind a substantial amount of scrap*" or "*you collect what scrap you can*".

I know that ships drop different scrap rewards [low, medium, and high] based on how you defeat them (killing the crew drops more scrap than destroying the ship, for example).

**Does the flavor text indicate which rewards I got?**

and if so, what flavor text corresponds to which rewards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flavour text does in fact correlate to the amount of scrap received. For ship fights in particular:

- *The ship explodes, leaving behind a substantial collection of useful scrap material.*

  This is the most common flavour text, received when you destroy the enemy's hull. This leaves you a **medium reward**, as well as some fuel, missiles, or drones.
- *There are no more life-signs remaining on the ship. You strip it of useful materials.*

  This is the next most common flavour text. This occurs about half the time that you suffocate or otherwise kill the enemy crew on a piloted (i.e. non-automatic) ship. This gives a **high reward** as well as fuel, missiles, or drones.
- *With the crew dead, you are able to take the fuel out of storage. You also take all the scrap you can manage.*

  This is an uncommon flavour text. It occurs about one in four times that you kill the crew. It yields a **high reward** in addition to some fuel, obviously.
- *Now that their ship has been emptied of hostiles, you search it. Eventually you find a prisoner who offers to join your crew.*

  This is a rare flavour text. It only happens if you kill the enemy crew. It gives a **medium reward** and a free crew member.
- *You find a weapon system on their ship. With no crew to stop you, you can install it on your own.*

  This is a rare flavour text. It only happens if you kill the enemy crew. It gives a **medium reward** and a free weapon.

Answer (score 1):

The various quests/events/ships that give you scrap will have a specific description *for that outcome.* The reward text for driving off an auto-scout from a fuel station is specific to *successfully driving off the auto-scout from a fuel station.* There are no particular keywords, phrases, or consistently-applied rules for the reward text; it's just whatever the author thought would sound good at the time.

If you really want to know whether you got a "high" reward or a low one, the only solution is to open up the data file in FTL that describes all of the events.